# Configuration pug under gulp

Tags: node.js, express, gulp, pug

How could I modify configuration of pug under gulp to exclude closing watch mode after every compile error?

```
gulp.task('pug', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/pug/**/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug({pretty: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app'))
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question please ?

Comment: Sure, when I did mistake in syntax or somwhere else in pugfile I'll take error under the gulp and crash gulp watch mode so have to rerun gulp watcher again and again till find and fix mistake in pugfile. When I do the same mistake in sass file, gulp just send message on terminal and watcher still working... so maybe solution is and I haven't find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plumber plugin in gulp.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    pug = require('gulp-pug');

gulp.task('pug', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/pug/**/*.pug')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(pug({pretty: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app'))
});
```